# What is the data format required for input in the IBM-Watson cloud product?

Tags: database, database-design, data-entry, ibm-watson

I'm having a hard time figuring out what type of data watson accepts: RDF triples, relational, delimited text, etc.

There's really no documentation anywhere.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Watson currently eats unstructured English Prose in HTML, Word Doc, Text, and certain formats of PDF.

Some API documentation can be found here: https://www.ibmdw.net/watson/wp-content/uploads/sites/19/2013/11/An-Ecosystem-Of-Innovation-Creating-Cognitive-Applications-PoweredByWatson.pdf

You can also get a bit more if you go to the bottom of the mobile developer challenge page that's here: ibmwatson.com (see 'Helpful Hints about Watson')

If there's other documentation you're looking for, specific feedback would be helpful to pass on

Comment: it also accepts zipped versions of the above-mentioned file formats

Comment: Oh Hello @LynnLangit!